# Why "CC=xxx echo $CC" can not change the environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When we use make, we can set CC before the command like `CC=clang make` to set the environment variable. So I also test echo, following is the result:

```
> export CC=123
> CC=xxx echo $CC
123
```

Why the result is not `xxx` ?

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/104

Comment: @Phantom0308 : If you do a `CC=123 printenv CC` and thus avoid parameter extension, it will work.

Comment: In short, arguments to the command are evaluated *before* calling the command. The `$CC` is evaluated and replaced with `123`, then the command `CC=xxx echo 123` is executed. Notice that the `CC=xxx` is not separate from the command here, it is part of the command. Compare it with: `CC=xxx; echo $CC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in the bash manual how [simple command expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) works.

The expansion of `$CC` occurs in step 2, as part of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).  This replaces `$CC` with `123`, so the command to be executed becomes

```
CC=xxx echo 123
```

The assignment of `xxx` to `CC` only happens in step 4.  So the overall effect is that the variable `CC` is set equal to `xxx`, added to the environment, and then the command `echo 123` is executed.  The output is then of course `123`.  Since the command `echo 123` doesn't make any use of the environment variable `CC`, the setting of `CC` has no effect.

So in order for a variable assignment to affect parameter expansion, it needs to have been done as a previous command: `CC=xxx ; echo $CC`.  If you don't want the current shell's environment to be affected, you can run both commands in a subshell: `( CC=xxx ; echo $CC )`, after which `echo $CC` will print `123` again.